# Is this Facebook, or do I have a rogue extension or whatnot?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

Recently I have noticed that I'm getting new reaction emojis, or whatever, when I click on notifications in the notification list on Facebook.

Here's an example:

[image]

I'm talking about the row of faces below my post.

Is this just native Facebook? Can I turn it off?

Or is this some rogue extension or whatnot that I have managed to get installed? Note, I did try to disable all extensions in Chrome, and reload Facebook and click on the same notification, but I still get them. I'm leaning towards Facebook having added these, it just seems odd since they've used "Bob's Burger" main character in one of them.

In any case, I don't really want these, can I get rid of them?

This is in Chrome running on Windows 11.

Comment: Have you reviewed your Facebook apps? [Facebook Help > Using Facebook >
Apps > Manage your apps](https://www.facebook.com/help/942196655898243/)